# dynamically embedding youtube videos with jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, youtube, embed, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve a listing of a user's youtube videos and embed them in a page using jQuery. My code looks something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  

  //some variables  
  var fl_obj_template = $('<object width="260" height="140">' +   
                          '<param name="movie" value=""></param>' +  
                          '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +  
                          '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +  
                          '<embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="260" height="140"></embed>' +  
                          '</object>');  

  var video_elm_arr = $('.video');  


  //hide videos until ready
  $('.video').addClass('hidden');

  //pull video data from youtube
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads?alt=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,item){
        //only take the first 7 videos
        if(i > 6)
          return;

        //give the video element a flash object
        var cur_flash_obj = fl_obj_template;

        //assign title
        $(video_elm_arr[i]).find('.video_title').html(item.title.$t);

        //clean url
        var video_url = item.media$group.media$content[0].url;
        var index = video_url.indexOf("?");
          if (index > 0)
            video_url = video_url.substring(0, index);

        //and asign it to the player's parameters
        $(cur_flash_obj).find('object param[name="movie"]').attr('value', video_url);
        $(cur_flash_obj).find('object embed').attr('src', video_url);

        //alert(cur_flash_obj);

        //insert flash object in video element
        $(video_elm_arr[i]).append(cur_flash_obj);

        //and show
        $(video_elm_arr[i]).removeClass('hidden');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

(of course with 'username' being the actual username).

The video titles appear correctly but no videos show up. What gives?

The target html looks like:

```
<div id="top_row_center" class="video_center video">
  <p class="video_title"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ajax only works on URLs from the same domain. Add a wrapper script on your own domain to retrieve the details. It's probably working because you're testing it with a local HTML file.

Comment: @Simon Brown that is usually the case but if you look at the Jquery page for .ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you will see that "Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Change:

```
var fl_obj_template = $('<object width="260" height="140">' +    
                          '<param name="movie" value=""></param>' +   
                          '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +   
                          '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +   
                          '<embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="260" height="140"></embed>' +   
                          '</object>');
```

To  This:

```
var fl_obj_template = '<object width="260" height="140">' +    
                          '<param name="movie" value=""></param>' +   
                          '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +   
                          '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +   
                          '<embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="260" height="140"></embed>' +   
                          '</object>';
```

I think the youtube code is being used as a seletor

Comment: I just wrapped it all in an append :)